# What are the lyrics to the Cathedral's theme song in TBoI?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

What are the full lyrics to the song from **The Binding of Isaac - *Cathedral's theme***?

It sounds like Latin (And even if it isn't, what are the translated lyrics?).

Answer (score 3):

"Libero ne tu salve" are the lyrics. Translating this is not straight forward, but you have interpret it almost? It basically translates to "I shall not let you leave unharmed" OR "You will exit of here without being harmed".

Two totally different meanings, but my Latin is a bit sketchy and google translate sucks at translating Latin.

The official title of this song is Lament of the Angel by Danny Baranowsky.

Comment: I've also thought so at first, but it's even specifically said in the source page that belongs to the newer game "The Binding of Isaac **(Rebirth)** OST - Heverlasting Hymn Cathedral". And the lyrics even sounds different.

Comment: @HashiramaSenju Changed my answer based on the actual title of the song.

Comment: Can you please provide the source for this info? It sounds like they're saying more than just what you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Libero = free, or rescue, or deliver;
no is a negative like not;
tu is you;
Salve is well or in good health.

So something like 'you [are] not free in good health?

I have the hunch its not a complete latin sentence. Did a few years in high school and usually latin sentences end with the verb, and salve is not a verb.

Comment on the youtube video seems to have a better guess on the meaning, which works with my translation:
"You shall not be freed without harm..."

EDIT: Rereading my answer from years ago, I feel important to say that in Latin, the structure of sentences is bonkers. Try speaking like Yoda. thats the sentence structure we are dealing with. Dont think you can just translate the latin to english and have a good idea of the sentence.

Comment: Salve is an imperative of salvere. 'Libero' seems first person singular, i.e. 'I liberate' or 'I set free'. For the rest I agree with you, it having a negative connotation, rather than a positive one, as the other answer suggest. My interpretation would be "I won't allow your well-being", but in Dog Latin.

Comment: My latin was now almost 15 years ago, so I might be rusty.

Comment: Considering that the whole theme of the game implies that Isaac is trapped in the chest all along and will die in there.... "You are not free" seems quite fitting.